# Menu separator with material design lite

Tags: html, css, menu, material-design-lite

I am writing a menu with material design lite and I need a separator between two categories of item in this menu.

I recreated a simpler example of what I am doing here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbJXQP

In this example I would like to have something to delimit the two different categories. In the example "Trip planner" and "Layers" are some map related widget whereas "Help" and "Send feedback" are more info related.

Specificaly here:

```
<li class="mdl-menu__item" 
  <i class="material-icons" >layers</i>  
     Layers</li>
<li class="mdl-menu__item" 
    onClick="javascript:webapp.infoWidgets['otp-infoWidget-0'].show();" >
    Help</li>
```

I am fairly new to web development (a few month), so I don't really have an idea of what is a good solution to do that.
For the separator it need to be something noticeable but not obtrusive to the user. I was thinking at just a straight black line in the middle but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Is the HTML fixed by necessity? Because it seems like a better decision would be to have two lists, rather than one, that way the related list-elements are contained within their own lists. Although each list could, of course, nested within an ancestor list.

Comment: ..an additional MDL class (I'm sure there must be one) for the first each special type of menu item which could then have a top border would be most logical.

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried to do that and the two lists appear next to each other  horizontally. It would be nice if I could get it to work the way you says. I will keep trying to do it and post feedback if I figure it out.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't really understand what you mean? Do you mind reexplaining? thanks

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML of the list in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a separate line, like you said. The `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break in an HTML page (e.g. a shift of topic). try this:

**HTML**

```
<li class="mdl-menu__item"> 
  <i class="material-icons" >layers</i>  
     Layers</li>
<li><hr></li>
<li class="mdl-menu__item" 
    onClick="javascript:webapp.infoWidgets['otp-infoWidget-0'].show();" >
    Help</li>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeLdKJ)**

Note: You can style by CSS the `<hr>` - https://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

Comment: @Paulie_D i  thought it was a CSS, HTML problem and not a UI/UX question . If is a UI/UX question, maybe is a good idea add those tags.

Comment: I like the solution because of its simplicity but @Paulie_D mark some points. If I don't find better I will use this.

Comment: It's is a HTML/CSS issue and a list item just for styling isn't semantic.

Comment: @Paulie_D I created this code so it could be used freely by th OP without being attached to another element for better styling. And yes i use a list item for that...it was my solution. Your solution above it´s only a border even with pseudo elements it will be hard, will not be never like a container . So my solution is a simple solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

An additional MDL class (I'm  not familiar with MDL but sure there must be one, if not, just create one) for the first each special type of menu item which could then have a top border would be most logical.

So, let's assume that the first of each informational list item has a class of `info`:

Then we can do.

```
.mdl-menu__item.info {
  border-top:1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BjNVbd)

There are a variety of techniques for selecting which list item to apply the border to.